# Auto print Date and Time on each page in MS word

Tags: ms-word

I am wondering if it is possible to have the date and time printed automatically in the (header or footer) of each newly created page in MS word.
Lets say I Opened MS-word on 10:30 AM and wrote some stuff, then on 11:34 I added some more notes in a new page can I have the first showing 10:30 and the second showing 11:34?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: @Chris, as far as I know it should be, as it involves writing a VB code or some code in MS-word to do that task.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is specific to Word 2010 but I don't think much has changed for newer versions.

There are a few of obstacles to doing this, the most important of which is that Word only allows a different header/footer for the first page, and for odd and even pages.

[image]

Also, there is no event handler for when new pages are created.

If these obstacles did not exist, you could create document properties and store dates & times in them. That part would be easy. But, alas, it is not possible.

Comment: I gave it a and i showed the text but unfortunately didn't do the auto-update, I have re-edit the header every-time.